# Unable to import SharePoint list in Excel when using Forms authentication

Tags: 2013, excel, powerpivot

I have a SharePoint team site published on the internet with forms authentication enabled. I can access it on browser using `http://myteamsite:1080` and then it displays a form where I enter my user/password. It works fine.

Problem is now I am trying to read data from a list but it is showing error
 `The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.`

Both screenshots showing how am I connecting and the error message are attached. How do I read data from list?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok this issue is fixed as I exported the list into Excel from SharePoint and then opened it from there. Here are the steps:

1. Go to your list and click on "Export to Excel" in ribbon above  
2. It will ask you to save file which for e.g. you save it on Desktop  
3. Now double click on file which will open Excel and then it will show you form authentication page. Enter user/password and you are done.